# How to display attempts for guessing the number

Tags: c++

I am a C++ beginner.
I need to write a C++ program to create a random number in range (0 - 10) then ask the user to guess that number.The user only has 3 attempts.
In case the user guessed a wrong number in the first 2 attempts print "TRY AGAIN ...".
In case the user got it right in first, second or third attempt print "YOU WIN", otherwise print "YOU
LOSE".

The output should be something like:

Created number is : 6.

Attempt number 1:

Guess the number: 2.

Try again!

Attempt number 2:

Guess the number: 6.

You win!

Here is my code. It seems there is something wrong!

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int guess, num;
    srand(time(0));

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        num = (rand() % 10) + 1;
        cout << num << endl;
        do
        {
            cout << "Enter a number between 1 and 10: ";
            cin >> guess;

            if (guess == num) {
                cout << "YOU WIN!\n\n";
                break;
            }
            else if (guess != num) {
                cout << "Try again!" << endl;
                break;
            }
            else
                cout << "YOU LOSE!" << endl;
        }

        while (guess != num);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: It seems there is something wrong in the code!

Comment: Could you please update your question with your exact problem and error? Otherwise people won't be able to help you

Answer (score 4):

You have two loops when you really just need one. Also your `return 0;` is in the wrong place. Also your `You lose!` statement can't be reached since the if/else if cover all branches.

You can simplfy this somewhat:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int guess, num;
    srand(time(0));
    num = (rand() % 10) + 1;
    cout << "number is: " << num << endl;

    constexpr int max_tries = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < max_tries;)
    {
        cout << "Enter a number between 1 and 10: ";
        cin >> guess;
        cout << guess << std::endl;

        if (guess == num)
        {
            cout << "YOU WIN!\n\n";
            return 0;
        }
        else if (++i < max_tries && guess != num)
        {
            cout << "Wrong - try again!" << endl;
        }               
    }
    cout << "Wrong - YOU LOSE!" << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Here you loop 3 times. If they get the right answer then `return 0;` exits the program there and then (and says you win). Otherwise you loop through the loop 3 times - if they have not won by the end of three loops then you get to the end of the program and print "you loose" and `return 1;`

Comment: @AzharYoussef slightly tweaked the answer below as per your request - that was deleted because you posted it as an answer :o ... but this should really be simple logical tweaks that you can attempt yourself : )